# AJAX Form submission error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that I want to validate on submission.

I have the following javascript...

```
var data = $('.sighting').serialize();
$.ajax({ url: "submit-process.php",
         data: data,
         type: "POST",
         success: function(data){
             $(".result").text('Thank you for your assistance.');
         },
         error: function(data) {
             $(".result").text(data);
         }
});
```

And I have the following PHP

```
<?php   
    if('date-seen' == '') { 
        echo 'fail' 
    } else {    
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            $message .= "Field ".htmlentities($key)." is ".htmlentities($value)."\r\n";

        mail('liam@site.co.uk', 'sghting', $message);    
    }   
?>
```

If the 'date-seen' input is left blank, I receive [Object, object] instead of 'fail' only then if I fill in this field and try resending It doesnt submit, which im guessing is an error in my PHP?

Any help would be brilliant, thanks.

Comment: 'date-seen' can never, evrer be equal to ' '. according to information you provided it shoud be $_POST['date-seen']==' '

Comment: Still no luck @KiroConeski, im receiving [object Object] even if the field is filled out?

Comment: In order to receive something readable you need to encode it in json format. So instead of echo 'fail', use echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'fail')). That way you'll receive an array of data, not an object

Comment: If you don't json_encode the output of the php script, the ajax call will always end up in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'date-seen' == ''` tests if two string literals are equal to each other (and they aren't).

You probably want `$_POST['date-seen']`

You also probably want to make your test:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['date-seen']) ) {
```

...instead of comparing a variable that does not exist to an empty string.

Comment: Still no luck @Quentin, im receiving [object Object] even if the field is filled out?

Comment: Where are you receiving it?

Comment: In my .result <p>...
error: function(data) {
                 $(".result").text(data);
               }

Comment: Then you should look at the raw HTTP response.